# BackgroundWorker starts other threads that have an exception. Exception not caught?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, exception, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` that I call from my main UI thread as follows.

On the MainWindow I declare the `BackgroundWorker`

```
 private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb = new BackgroundWorker();
```

And in the constructor I set it up as follows.

```
        backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb.DoWork +=
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb_DoWork);
        backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb.RunWorkerCompleted +=
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb.ProgressChanged +=
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
```

At the end of the constructor I call the following method to start it on its way.

```
 private void RefreshWebDataTimer(Object state)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb.IsBusy && !backgroundWorkerLoadFromDB.IsBusy)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Refresh Timer Started at {0}", DateTime.Now);
                backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb.RunWorkerAsync(nfl);
            }
        }
```

The `DoWork` event handler calls a method from another project (DLL).  That method has a pattern which calls multiple threads to do process work.  when one of those threads throws an error, the application crashed and the `BackgroundWorker` does not catch it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.  The pattern is a complex (probably overly complicated) but is as follows.

In the method the DoWork event handler calls I create a set of "sub-worker" threads in a wrapper as follows...and then WAIT for all threads to finish processing before moving on.

```
private static void GetRoster(Nfl teams, ref ManualResetEvent[] mre, ref int index)
{
    mre = new ManualResetEvent[Dictionary.NUMBER_OF_NFL_TEAMS];
    ParseDataAsyncWrapper[] dw = new ParseDataAsyncWrapper[Dictionary.NUMBER_OF_NFL_TEAMS];

    index = 0;
    foreach (NflTeam team in teams)
    {

            //Get Roster and create players

                mre[index] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                dw[index] = new ParseDataAsyncWrapper(team, mre[index]);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(dw[index].RosterCallbackAsync), index++);//Don't fully understand this  
                Thread.Sleep(wait.Next(Dictionary.THREAD_WAIT_MS));
   }
    foreach (ManualResetEvent re in mre) { if (re != null) { re.WaitOne(); } } //Wait for all threads to finish
    mre = null; //allow to be disposed
    dw = null;
}
```

I use the callback for each thread to get a webpage and then process that page:

```
internal async void RosterCallbackAsync(object State)
{
    if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null) { Thread.CurrentThread.Name = string.Format("Roster{0}", State); }
    WebPage = await Html.WebClientRetryAsync(Dictionary.ROSTER_WEBPAGE.Replace(Dictionary.CITY_REPLACE_STR, this.Team.CityAbr));

    Html.ParseRoster(WebPage, Team);

    DoneEvent.Set();
}
```

I am then throwing the exception in Html.ParseRoster but it is not getting caught.  This is on a different thread than the `BackgroundWorker`.  I don't know why the `BackgroundWorker` is not catching it.  Since I am waiting for all threads to finish before moving on I don't think the `RunWorkerCompleted` event would run before I am done here.

I've looked at the help page for [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) and it states:

> you will need to write code to do the following: Handle exceptions on
>   the background thread. Dispatch those exceptions to the main UI
>   thread. Rethrow them on the main UI thread without handling them to
>   allow DispatcherUnhandledException to be raised.

My question is 1) Why is the excpetion not being caught?  Should I use `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` and if so how can I accomplish this?  I would ultimately like to throw these exceptions to the `BackgroundWorker`.  Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have been working on using TPL with await/async and Tasks and updated my code.  This has been somewhat successfull as I am now getting the exception back to the `BackgroundWorker`. Ignoring how I get the exception back to the `DoWork` event for now ... I check that I am getting an exception by adding a try/catch block and am catching and re-throwing the exception. Here is my `DoWork` event

```
   private async void backgroundWorkerRefreshFromWeb_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly. 
        // Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Start the time-consuming operation.
        NflStatsComplete = false;
        bw.ReportProgress(0, "Starting Data Refresh from Web...");
        try
        {
           e.Result = await Html.RetrieveWebData(bw, e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        // If the operation was canceled by the user,  
        // set the DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel property to true. 
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

In the debugger I get an exception and see it thrown.  However, when it then goes to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e` shows `e.Error == null`.  I don't understand how this can be since I am throwing an exception directly from the `DoWork` event.  Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Application.DispatcherUnhandledException does what it says, it reports exceptions for code that was executed by the dispatcher.  In other words, not code on a worker thread.  You are digging yourself a pretty deep hole, consider it a learning experience.

Comment: BackgroundWorkers do not nest well. I recommend using `Task.Run` or `async` methods instead of `BackgroundWorker` and `QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: @HansPassant So I guess Application.DispatcherUnhandledException is the wrong way to go.  Do you know why this exception wouldn't get caught by the BackgroundWorker or what I need to do in order to get it recognized by the RunWorkerCompleted e.Error property?

Comment: I see ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem().  That's not a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @HansPassant I have updated the beginning of my question to make it more clear how the BackgroundWorker is setup.

Comment: @StephenCleary.  I found `Event-based Asynchronous Pattern Overview` [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw(v=vs.90).aspx] and am looking at that idea to replace the `QueueuUserWorkItem`.  Do you think that approach would be a good choice?

Comment: @Harrison: No. Use the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern.

Comment: You should have your threads catch those exceptions and communicate an error status back. You'll never get cross-thread exception handling to work the way you want. Tasks are set up to make returning error status fairly painless.

Comment: @StephenCleary.  Looking at TAP, it looks like I have a lot of refactoring to do, but it will simplify my error handling. Thanks.

Comment: @JimMischel That answers a lot of my questions, Thanks.  Since I have exceptions on other threads, I'm not getting back what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Backgroundworker is setup as an async method. I believe this is causing the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to fire before the `DoWork` event has completed and the exception has been raised.  By updating the DoWork method to remove the async compiler keyword and removing any awaits the exception propogates back to the method specified by the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and `e.Error != null`